# Как получить поля модели User?

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Я наследую модель от User:

```
class UserProfile(User):            
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        verbose_name='Пол',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Отображаемое имя',
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )   
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )
    skype = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )   
    other = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=False,
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='userprofile/avatar/', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    @classmethod
    def get_new_authors_entries(self, cut_begin=0, cut_end=2):
        return self.objects.filter(is_active=1, is_superuser=0)[cut_begin:cut_end]
```

В результате `get_new_authors_entries()` возвращает следующий массив данных:

```
[
        {
            "fields": 
                {
                    "skype": "dfsdf", 
                    "user_permissions": [], 
                    "other": "zzzz", 
                    "nickname": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0422\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0432 \u0451\u043f\u0442\u0430", 
                    "gender": 1, 
                    "avatar": "", 
                    "phone": "2014-0921", 
                    "groups": []
                },

            "model": "app_accounts.userprofile", 
            "pk": 4
        },

        .....,
        .....,
        ....
    ]
```

Проблема в том, что этот массив не содержит полей: `'date_joined'`, `'username'`, `'email'`, а они есть в модели User. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить их.

Вот фрагмент из контроллера:

```
new_authors = UserProfile.get_new_authors_entries(cut_begin=page_new_authors, cut_end=page_new_authors + 2)

result = serializers.serialize('json', new_authors)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866105/json-serialization-of-a-django-inherited-model известная проблема. Правда, оба тикета в джанго закрыты, так что сначала попробуйте обновить версию.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам просто нужно унаследоваться от модели [`AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/), вместо `User`.